# What is an optimal way to make tandoori roti and naan in big green egg?

Tags: baking, bread, oven, indian-cuisine

Big green egg (and other kamado style ovens) can be used for many kinds of different breads. What is an optimal way to bake naan and/or tandoori roti in an egg( large size)? 
Traditionally clay ovens is India have long hollow cylindrical structure where the bread is stuck, not sure how we can replicate the same behavior in Big Green Egg. Use in on the plate setter or use a pizza stone or stick it on the inside of the upper some? 
What should the temperature be? How long should it be left? Any other useful information regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

I make naan on my BGE all the time. You can't replicate a tandoor, however, the results are very good. I find it best to cook the naan directly on the grill, and over the coals.  I find lower heat is best.  I either bake them at the end of a grill session, when the heat is dying, or I completely close the bottom vent (leaving the lid open...not just the lid vent). Depending on the heat level, it only takes a minute or two on each side.  I place the rolled out naan on the grill, lightly brush with melted butter, wait for bubbling/puffing, flip, brush with butter, wait for puffing (or peak underneath and look for doneness), then remove to a towel for holding...repeat.